# Application not displaying GUI and won't quit Java

Tags: java

So I'm creating a game in Java and I ran into a little problem.  Whenever I run the application the GUI does not show on the screen and the only way to close the application is to use the Windows Task Manager.  In the application, you choose a username and click an enter button which creates a new window in which the game is played.  But after you click the button, none of the GUI loads and you can't close the application.

Basically, when you click the button, a method is called that disposes the current window and starts the game window.  The code for that method is below:

```
public void login(String name) {
    String[] args={};
    dispose();
    SingleplayerGUI.main(args);
}
```

And here is the code of the SingleplayerGUI class:

```
public SingleplayerGUI(String userName, Singleplayer sp) {
    this.userName = userName;
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Console Clash Singleplayer");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(880, 550);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    System.setIn(inPipe); 
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true));
        inWriter = new PrintWriter(new PipedOutputStream(inPipe), true); 
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] { 28, 815, 30, 7 }; // SUM = 880
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[] { 25, 485, 40 }; // SUM = 550
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    history = new JTextPane();
    history.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(history);
    caret = (DefaultCaret) history.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    GridBagConstraints scrollConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    scrollConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    scrollConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    scrollConstraints.gridx = 0;
    scrollConstraints.gridy = 0;
    scrollConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    scrollConstraints.gridheight = 2;
    scrollConstraints.weightx = 1;
    scrollConstraints.weighty = 1;
    scrollConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, -64);
    contentPane.add(scroll, scrollConstraints);

    txtMessage = new JTextField();
    txtMessage.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                Color color = new Color(92, 219, 86);
                String text = txtMessage.getText();
                inWriter.println(text); 
                console(txtMessage.getText(), color);
                command = txtMessage.getText();
            }
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtMessage = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtMessage.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 25);
    gbc_txtMessage.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtMessage.gridx = 0;
    gbc_txtMessage.gridy = 2;
    gbc_txtMessage.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc_txtMessage.weightx = 1;
    gbc_txtMessage.weighty = 0;
    txtMessage.setColumns(5);
    contentPane.add(txtMessage, gbc_txtMessage);

    chat = new JTextPane();
    chat.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane chatscroll = new JScrollPane(chat);
    caret = (DefaultCaret) chat.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    GridBagConstraints chatscrollConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    chatscrollConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    chatscrollConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    chatscrollConstraints.gridx = 0;
    chatscrollConstraints.gridy = 0;
    chatscrollConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    chatscrollConstraints.gridheight = 2;
    chatscrollConstraints.weightx = 1;
    chatscrollConstraints.weighty = 1;
    chatscrollConstraints.insets = new Insets(150, 600, 5, -330);
    contentPane.add(chatscroll, chatscrollConstraints);

    chatMessage = new JTextField();
    final String name = this.userName;
    chatMessage.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                chatconsole(name + ": " + chatMessage.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_chatMessage = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtMessage.insets = new Insets(000, 600, 000, -330);
    gbc_txtMessage.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtMessage.gridx = 0;
    gbc_txtMessage.gridy = 2;
    gbc_txtMessage.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc_txtMessage.weightx = 1;
    gbc_txtMessage.weighty = 0;
    txtMessage.setColumns(5);
    contentPane.add(chatMessage, gbc_txtMessage);

    JButton btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    btnSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color color = new Color(92, 219, 86);
            String text = txtMessage.getText();
            inWriter.println(text); 
            console(txtMessage.getText(), color);
            command = txtMessage.getText();
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnSend = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnSend.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 275);
    gbc_btnSend.gridx = 2;
    gbc_btnSend.gridy = 2;
    gbc_btnSend.weightx = 0;
    gbc_btnSend.weighty = 0;
    contentPane.add(btnSend, gbc_btnSend);

    list = new JList();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_list.insets = new Insets(0, 600, 330, -330);
    gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_list.gridx = 0;
    gbc_list.gridy = 0;
    gbc_list.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc_list.gridheight = 2;
    JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane();
    p.setViewportView(list);
    contentPane.add(p, gbc_list);
    list.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 0, 24));

    System.out.println("HEY");

    setVisible(true);

    new SwingWorker<Void, String>() { 
         protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception { 
            Scanner s = new Scanner(outPipe);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                     String line = s.nextLine();
                     publish(line);
            }
            return null; 
        } 
         @Override protected void process(java.util.List<String> chunks) { 
             for (String line : chunks) {
                try {
                    Document doc = history.getDocument();
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), line + "\r\n", null);
                } catch(BadLocationException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
         } 

    }.execute(); 

    Singleplayer spp = new Singleplayer();
    Singleplayer.startOfGame();

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void console(String message, Color color) {
    txtMessage.setText("");
    try {
        StyledDocument doc = history.getStyledDocument();
        Style style = history.addStyle("", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, color);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), message + "\r\n", style);
    } catch(BadLocationException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void console(String message) {
    txtMessage.setText("");
    try {
        Document doc = history.getDocument();
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), message + "\r\n", null);
    } catch(BadLocationException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void chatconsole(String message) {
    chatMessage.setText("");
    try {
          Document doc = chat.getDocument();
          doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), message + "\r\n", null);
       } catch(BadLocationException exc) {
          exc.printStackTrace();
       }
}

public static void single() {
    Singleplayer sp = new Singleplayer();
    new SingleplayerGUI("", sp);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singleplayer sp = new Singleplayer();
    new SingleplayerGUI("", sp);
}
```

And the singleplayer class:

```
public static void startOfGame(){
    System.out.println("HEY");
    SingleplayerGUI.console("Welcome to Console Clash Pre Alpha Version 1!");
    SingleplayerGUI.console("Created by Drift");
    SingleplayerGUI.console("Published by Boring Games");
    SingleplayerGUI.console("");
    SingleplayerGUI.console("");
    menuScreen();
}

static void menuScreen() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("To play the game, type 'start'.  To quit, type 'quit'.");
        String menu = scan.nextLine();
        if (menu.equals("start")) {
            start();
        } else if (menu.equals("quit")) {
            quit();
        } else {
            menuScreen();
        }
}

private static void quit() {
    SingleplayerGUI.console("You quit the game.");
}

private static void start() {
    SingleplayerGUI.console("You started the game.");
}
```

So far I've figured out that the problem most likey occurs when adding the outPipe to the console.  Would I be able to fix this or am I just not able to use outPipes with this application?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When you ask questions, you should try and make some effort to reduce the amount of code displayed to the bare minimum needed to illustrate the issue. The fact that your GUI code is littered with user input logic and game logic makes it hard to pin point exactly what could be going wrong. And am I correct in assuming that there is no error being reported in the JVM console?

Comment: You are also not showing some parts of the code that are very important. For example, it looks like you made `SinglePlayerGUI` extend another class, but you do not show that section of the code. I would assume its a `JFrame` or `JPanel`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about all the code.  You are correct; there are no errors.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about telling you about that.  The SingleplayerGUI class extends JFrame.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I guess I could switch you JavaFX but that would take a lot of time to learn and I'd like to stick with what I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

The setVisible() method is invoked twice.. Remove the second setVisible() call after the Singleplayer.startOfGame(); line in SingleplayerGUI constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the same problem occurs even after I removed the second setVisible call.